# count number of uniq paths in maze

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I know the backtracking approach to count path [0,0] to [n,n] in matrix. but not able to solve it by dynamic programming. Is it even possible without backtracking ??

you can move only `right` or `down`

`1 1 1 1`
`1 0 1 1`
`1 1 0 1`
`1 1 1 1`
`

number of path to reach from top left to bottom right is 4

Comment: Are you familiar with Pascal's Triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. Say p(i,j) is the number of partial paths to i,j. If we're using zero-indexing then what you want is p(n-1,n-1). What you know is that p(0,0)=1, also p(i,j) is the sum of the value to the left if you can travel from p(i-1,j) to p(i,j), and the value above if you can travel from p(i,j-1) to p(i,j).

So you use all that to fill out a matrix. Pretty much that's what DP is: matrix-filling. Once you figure out how to fill out the matrix you're done.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static int numPath = 0;
    // Take one sol[][] of same size as original matrix just to see your paths.
    private static boolean MazeSolvingAllPaths(int [][] matrix, int x, int y, int[][] sol) {


        //Base case
        if(x == (sizeofMatrix -1) && y == (sizeofMatrix -1)) {
            sol[x][y] = 1;
            numPath++; // Path found so increase numPath here
            return true;
        }
        if(isSafeAllPaths(matrix, x, y) == true && matrix[x][y] == 1) {
            sol[x][y] = 1; // Mark this as solution path in solution matrix
            // Go right and down for (x, y)
            boolean var1 = MazeSolvingAllPaths(matrix, x, y+1, sol);
            boolean var2 = MazeSolvingAllPaths(matrix, x+1, y, sol);
            // If atleast one solution i found then return true
            if(var1 || var2) {                  
                return true;
            } else { // means both var1 and var2 are false
                sol[x][y] = 0;// unmark because i couldn't find path
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is the backtracking solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use dynamic programming to solve this.

- Given a `M x N` maze, initialize an array `paths` with the same dimensions. Let `paths[i][j]` be the number of possible paths from
  `maze[0][0]` to `maze[i][j]`.
- Initialize `paths[0][0]` to `1`.
- If `maze[i][j] == 0`, then `paths[i][j] = 0` else `paths[i][j] =
  paths[i-1][j] + paths[i][j-1]`.

Here's a Python implementation:

```
def number_of_paths(maze):
    paths = [[0 for col in range(len(maze[0]))] for row in range(len(maze))]
    paths[0][0] = 1

    for row in range(len(maze)):
        for col in range(len(maze[0])):
            if maze[row][col] == 0:
                paths[row][col] = 0
            else:
                if row != 0:
                    paths[row][col] += paths[row-1][col]
                if col != 0:
                    paths[row][col] += paths[row][col-1]
    return paths[-1][-1]

maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]]

print(number_of_paths(maze))  # 4
```